# How does Google Reader's progress icon work

Tags: html, css, reverse-engineering

Not sure if this is the place to ask, but anyways. I collect small [progress indicators](http://zanstra.home.xs4all.nl/picks/progress.html). They are mostly animated GIF's, but I also like some CSS3/javascript ones. For some time now I try to isolate Google Reader's indicator, but I haven't been succesful. And since it's [being discontinued](http://googlereader.blogspot.ca/2013/03/powering-down-google-reader.html) per July 1st 2013, I don't have much time left!

In the bottom right corner of Reader, sometimes an animation of a circle is shown, appearing in the Google colors. Using Chrome Developer Tools, I've found an HTML subtree, starting with`<div id="activity-indicator">`. [I've isolated](https://www.dropbox.com/home/Public/google-reader?select=index.html.txt) the HTML and the CSS, and I also saved the PNG image.

Probably some Javascript is also needed, so I put the *Break on Subtree Modifications* and *Break on Attributes modifications* breakpoints on the above mentioned HTML structure. However, stepping through the (unreadable) code, I see not much of an animation. The only thing I see happening, is a `hidden` class is applied to the activity-indicator DIV.

Does anyone have some pointers, how to isolate this animation? I really would like to have it (in it's original form). Thanks.